# How can I retrieve a user's disabled status from firebase auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I've implemented Firebase Authentication in my app with role-based API using firebase admin. When [retrieving a user's data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data) or [listing all user's data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) from firebase, it does not include the user's disabled status.

I'm attempting to create the ability for app administrators to tell if a user account is Active or Disabled, and have the option to "flip the switch" as needed to manage their users.

Here are my controllers for each route in the API:

**List all Users**

```js
    // list all users route
    app.get('/users', [
      authenticationCheck.isAuthenticated,
      authorizedCheck.isAuthorized({ hasRole: ['admin', 'user'] }),
      indexController.all,
    ])
      
    // list all users controller
    async function all(req, res) {
      try {
        const listUsers = await admin.auth().listUsers(),
          users = listUsers.users.map(mapUser)
        console.log('userList', users)
        return res.status(200).send({ users })
      } catch (err) {
        return handleError(res, err)
      }
    }
```

**Get user by id**

```js
    // get user by id route
    app.get('/users/:id', [
      authenticationCheck.isAuthenticated,
      authorizedCheck.isAuthorized(
        { hasRole: ['admin', 'user'], allowSameUser: true },
      ),
      indexController.get,
    ])

    // get user by id controller
    async function get(req, res) {
      try {
        const { id } = req.params,
          user = await admin.auth().getUser(id)
        return res.status(200).send({ user: mapUser(user) })
      } catch (err) {
        return handleError(res, err)
      }
    }
```

Am I missing something? How do I retrieve a user's disabled status from Firebase using Firebase Admin?

## Update

This issue is resolved. I found that the I wasn't mapping "disabled" in the mapUser function that I am using to also map customClaims.

Comment: `listUsers()` function does return array of UserRecords in user property. What is the output when you log users ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj, great question. This is what Firebase returns: 
{
    "users": [
        {
            "uid": "user-id",
            "email": "user's-email",
            "displayName": "user's display name",
            "role": "custom role",
            "lastSignInTime": "Sun, 13 Feb 2022 17:24:22 GMT",
            "creationTime": "Thu, 13 Jan 2022 14:04:56 GMT"
        },
        {
         ... repeated for the next user
        },
    ]
}

Comment: I found the issue. "Disabled" wasn't included in my mapUser function, where I was also mapping custom claims. This issue is resolved.